# Prove that $f$ has an inflection point at zero if $f$ is a function that satisfies a given set of hypotheses

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Prove that if $f$ is a function such that $f'(x) > 0$ $\forall x \neq 0 \wedge f'(0) = 0 \wedge f''$ is a continuous one to one function on some open interval $(a, b): a < 0 < b$ then $f$ must have an inflection point at zero.

I think that should the function $g$ be set to $g(x) = x^3$ then $g$ satisfies these hypotheses. The derivative of $g$ is $g'(x) = 3x^2$, which has $g'(x) > 0$ $\forall x \neq 0 \wedge g'(0) = 0$. The second derivative of $g$ is $g''(x) = 6x$ which is a linear function $\implies g''$ is a continuous one to one function $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. It is true that $g$ changes sign (has an inflection point) at $x = 0$. So, in this case, all these things make a reasonable amount of intuitive sense, but clearly these hypotheses being true for $x^3$ isn't proof for the general case. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what this would imply for a general function that fits all of these characteristics.

It seems that for a function $f$ to satisfy these hypotheses it must be some function $f(x) = x^n ... + \text{ }c$ where $n: n \geq 3$ and $n$ is some odd integer and $c$ is a constant. This would imply that $f'(x)$ is of even-degree, and $f''(x)$ is of odd-degree.

It's a bit confusing to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex has prodded me to a more elementary solution, so here is a second try: Suppose $f''(0)>0.$ Then by continuity of $f'',$ $f''> 0$ in a neighborhood of $0.$ This implies $f'$ is strictly increasing near $0.$ But $f'(0)=0.$ Thus $f'<0$ to left of $0$ and $f'>0$ to the right - at least near $0.$ That is a contradiction. Same idea if we assume $f''(0)<0.$ Thus $f''(0)=0.$ Now since $f''$ is given to be continuous and 1-1 near $0,$ $f''$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing near $0.$ In either case, $f''$ changes sign at $0,$ which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: So this would begin by assuming that $f''(0)$ is either greater than or less than $0$, which would result in a contradiction because it would imply that $f'$ is at some point less than $0$, which it is not, showing that it must be 0, in order for $f'$ to always be greater than or equal to $0$? A value $v$ on $f''$ such that $f''(v) = 0$ is an inflection point, hence $f''(0)$ is an inflection point?

Comment: Does that seem accurate, what I've said?

Comment: No, $f''(0) = 0$ by itself does not imply an inflection point. Example: $f(x) =x^4,x=0.$ An inflection point is where we change from strictly convex to strictly concave or vice-versa. In this problem we have proved $f''(0)=0$ *and* $f''$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Thus $f''$ must change from positivity to negativity, or vice-versa, at $0.$ That proves $f$ has an inflection point at $0.$

Comment: How do we test that? Do we just have to take values greater and less than 0? Or, we don't, because the function is given to be 1-1 which implies that?

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, $f(0)=0.$ Because $f'(0)=0,$ Taylor says $f(x) = f''(0)x^2/2 +o(x^2).$ Suppose $f''(0)>0.$ Then $f$ has a strict local minimum at $0.$ But the condition on $f'$ implies $f$ is strictly increasing. That's a contradiction. Similarly, $f''(0)<0$ is ruled out. Therefore $f''(0)=0.$ Now $f''$ is given to be one-to-one and continuous in a neighborhood of $0.$. Thus $f''$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing there. In either case, $f''$ changes sign at $0,$ giving the desired point of inflection.

Comment: "Taylor says $f(x)=f′′(0)x2/2+o(x^2)$". I don't know what this means.

Comment: Can you maybe explain your process a little more intricately for me? I am still uncertain of what you mean by your first statement.

Comment: What does Taylor's theorem say for functions twice continuously differentiable?

Comment: I am uncertain. I've never been introduced to Taylor's theorem, so I would've never thought to use it. I'll give it a look, though. I'm only a first year calculus student, and we've just begun applications of derivatives this month (minimising and maximising functions and the like).